# Create quarterly dates vector for plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, date, plot

How can I transform this (much longer) vector into quarterly values like Q1-1991 etc. that plot nicely on a graph in Matlab? I googled/Matlab-help-searched/searched in this forum and didn't find anything.

```
Dates = [19961; 19962; 19963; 19964; 19971; 19972]
```

Comment: Please show your exact expected output

Comment: @SardarUsama Probably strings, like so: `19961 -> 1996 1 -> 1996 Q1 -> "Q1-1996"`.

Comment: @Dev-iL makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MATLAB handles this kind of problem best using a data type specially designed for representing dates, [`datetime`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html). Starting from your `Dates` vector you want to:

1. Convert `Dates` from a `double` array to a `datetime` array.
2. Set the default format of the array to use your preferred format for quarter numbers
3. Use the `datetime` array directly in whatever graphs or other display you want the quarters shown.

You need to do a bit of numeric manipulation to get the components of the date into real quantities representing the bits of the date rather than a number engineered to look "datey" when displayed in decimal.

```
Years = floor(Dates / 10);
Quarters = rem(Dates, 10);
```

`datetime` objects describe the date of a specific day, so now that we know the quarter any day falling in the quarter will do. The simplest way to construct them is with a year, month and day, so I'm picking the first day of the middle month of the quarter to avoid any ambiguity in the boundary between quarters:

```
Months = Quarters * 3 - 1;
ProperDates = datetime(Years, Months, 1);
```

This new array has a [`Format`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html#d120e224603) property that determines how the date gets displayed such as when in plots:

```
ProperDates.Format = 'QQQ-yyyy`;
```

This array can now be supplied as data for `plot`s and other places where the date will be displayed and they will be displayed in the "Q1-1991" format automatically.